# Poor font rendering PDF-XChange Viewer running Wine

Tags: windows, wine, emulation

I cannot find a solution for the problem I had. I had to use a program like PDF XChange Viewer to get an annotation interface for my work, as it stands the above program is the most stable I have found, unfortunately for me the font, despite rendered probably is despicable and text cannot be worked upon in full screen mode as it could in native adobe reader 9 for ubuntu. Fonts in acroread are larger and good looking and seem to fill a better portion of the full screened page that ported program. Any viable way one can increase the size or change font style for that app, for  I have to stick to acroread however unoptimized it is. thank you

Comment: I still got this problem, and looking for a resolution as no alternative is available to those who wish to annotate an ebook!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and could solve it by installing 'winetricks'.
Once installed you have several options to configure or "tweak" wine. What solved my problem was this simple command:

```
winetricks corefonts
```

It installs the Microsoft fonts into Wine so that the PDF-X Change Viewer has access to them.

I hope this helps.
Best,
   Stefan

Comment: There is a playonlinux bug that it can't download from its GUI interface so if you are using playonlinux add a link: $ ln -s /home/user/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/Fonts ~/.fonts after the $ winetricks corefonts